# Webform: change the way each component is displayed?

Tags: webforms, forms

What I'm trying to achieve: I want to show my webform so each input would be displayed on separate page (kind of wizard or form with steps). I know that usually this is done by adding page breaks at desired position, but I have more than 80 elements and adding page break after each of them is super awful idea.

My plan is the following: create a module that'll override renderers of all elements except fieldset. My renderer will call original renderer and wrap its return value in `#type => 'container'` element with specific `class`. On page there'll be a piece of JS that'll show/hide specific fields depending on field state.

But there are no hooks that allow me to override element rendering, overriding it with `hook_form_alter` looks to be a bad idea: I'll have to recursively walk through passed form. I think there should be a different way.

So how do I override the way element is rendered?

Or am I getting this completely wrong and webform should be replaced with something more appropriate for my task?

Comment: What I understand from your question is that you are looking for a multi-step / multi-page form. If I am right, you can search for this terms to find an answer to your question.

Comment: @ЕлинЙ. I did numerous tries with other tools but still webform wins especially when you give it to users. In the end I've managed to make webform wizard-style using lots of JS. This plays well with Clientside Validation and Webform Conditionals while storing pre-submit values in localStorage. If I won't find anything better then this is the way I'll go.